# @MockBean not fluent with testNG

Tags: spring-boot, testng, spring-test

With JUnit i could use @MockBean easily :

```
    @SpringBootTest(classes = AppConfig.class)
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public @Log class ServiceDrhImplTest_JUnit {

        private @Autowired ServiceDrh serviceDrh;
        private @MockBean EmployeDao employeDao;
        private @MockBean SalaireDao salaireDao;
```

BUT with TestNG it doesn't work out of the box, with the abov syntax, the mocks are null.
I have to add @Autowired to @MockBean to make it works.
Further more mocks are not reset after each test, i have to had :

```
    @SpringBootTest(classes = AppConfig.class)
    public @Log class ServiceDrhImplTest_TestNG extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

        private @Autowired ServiceDrh serviceDrh;
        private @MockBean @Autowired EmployeDao employeDao;
        private @MockBean @Autowired SalaireDao salaireDao;

        @AfterMethod
        public void afterMethod() {
            Mockito.reset(employeDao, salaireDao);
        }
```

Do you confirm this behavior ?
Does it mean that Spring is stopping to support TestNG since it does not appear in spring-boot ref doc anymore ?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is already known by Spring and not yet fixed: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7689

And even if the documentation of Spring Boot doesn't reference TestNG, it provides a test sample for TestNG: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-testng

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error here in the future now that Spring Boot does support TestNG.

My fix for this was to make sure my test class extends `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` and has the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ClockConfig.class, UtilDate.class})
public class UtilDateTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
   @Inject
   @MockBean
   Clock clock;

   @Inject
   UtilDate utilDateUnderTest;

   @Test
   public void testUtilDate() {
       // mock clock
       // test utilDateUnderTest
   }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class ClockConfig {

    @Bean
    public Clock clock() { ... }
}
```

```java
@Named
public class UtilDate
{
    @Inject
    private Clock clock;
}
```